# Connect Postgresql from Docker Swarm Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine, docker-registry

I have 5 microservices which I intend to deploy over docker swarm cluster consisting of 3 nodes.

I also have a postgresql service running over one of the 3 servers(not dockerized but rather installed over the server) which I have. I did assign the network as "host" for all of the services but they simply refuse to start with no logs being generated.

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  frontend-client:
    image: xxx:10
    container_name: frontend
    restart: on-failure
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
    networks:
      - "host"
    ports:
      - "xxxx:3000"

networks:
  host:
    name: host
    external: true
```

I also did try to start a centos container from a server which does not have postgres installed and was able to ping as well as telnet the postgresql port as well using the Host network being assigned to it.

Can someone please help me narrow down the issue or look at the possibility which I might be missing???

Answer (score 0):

docker swarm doesn't support "host" network_mode currently, so your best bet (and best practice) would be to pass your postgresql host ip address as an environment variable to the services using it.

if you are using docker-compose instead of docker swarm, you can set network_mode to host:

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  frontend-client:
    image: xxx:10
    container_name: frontend
    restart: on-failure
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "xxxx:3000"
```

notice i've removed `networks` part of your compose snippet and replaced it with `network_mode`.

Comment: Got the following error whilst using **network_host**

`Ignoring unsupported options: network_mode`

Comment: this is because of the fact that you are using docker-swarm. `network_mode` is only supported in docker-compose.

Comment: But the plans are to have services over docker swarm and not on individual basis using docker-compose over the nodes that we currently have.